# Is metaoptimize.com part of the Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta, clone

Have been using [metaoptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/) for a while now and didn't even notice that there are some subtle differences, so does it belong to the SE family or it's just clone of the stackoverflow idea?

Comment: Funny, the name of their badges are changed but some of the desciptions are identical. Its just so not SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It **doesn't** have the SE 1.0 meta tag:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

and it has "powered by OSQA" in the footer.

So it's just a clone.

Comment: Did notice these bits and have thought about quiet launch maybe??  It looks like this Q&A model SE is offering is just the best for communication and there will be more and more sites inspired by stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @matcheek - the SE 2.0 sites are all about generating traffic so there won't be a "quiet launch".

Comment: In that case they shouldn't be allowed to use Stack Exchange now would they?

Answer (score 11):

MetaOptimize runs off of [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/), which is <s>a blatant ripoff of StackExchange</s> an open-source alternative Q&A engine. It isn't otherwise affiliated with SO.